# Set up AWS RDS persistence layer in Docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I want to set up a Docker container which shall store its data in a an RDS MariaDB auf AWS. What is the best way to Imtegrate the RDS instance into the Docker container to make sure no data get lost, even, when the Docker container fails.

Merci A

Answer (score 2):

"[Integrate] the RDS instance into the Docker container" does not make sense.

RDS is a managed database service. It is completely independent of any applications. You create a database instance and connect to it from your applications, using whatever connection mechanism your language/platform supports.

Docker is a framework that isolates applications from the hardware used to run them. In the AWS world, you could deploy a Docker container on an EC2 instance, or in an ECS (Elastic Container Service) cluster.

It is possible to run a DBMS inside a container, but that's not RDS.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the formulation was improper. I just want to use a rds database as a permanent datastore for my container. How can I do that. I have read something about using Docker volumes...

Comment: @aerioeus - Docker volumes aren't going to do anything for you unless you plan to run the database in Docker. Which you can do, _but it isn't RDS_.

Comment: If you want to use an RDS database, you create the database and connect to it from your application. How you do that depends on your application.

Comment: I want to connect it to a Docker container running on AWS ECS. But couldn’t find any guideline though AWS is usually very thorough providing such.

Answer (score 0):

However you would configure an application running directly on that EC2 instance to talk to RDS, or any other external database: do the exact same thing in your Docker setup.  You might need to pass the RDS host name as an environment variable or otherwise cause it to be injected.  You do not need to launch any special Docker containers, or set up volumes, or anything else; just use the database normally.

Comment: Could you provide an example dockerfile for me?that is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I'd highly recommend (a) writing the application, talking to RDS as you normally would, _totally ignoring Docker_; and then (b) following [Docker's official custom image tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) to package it up.  There's nothing special in the Dockerfile to talk to RDS (or any other off-host database).